# How can I specify two possible file paths for an image in JS?

Tags: javascript, filepath

I've done a few searches on this via Google and the Stack Overflow search bar, and nothing relevant shows up. I'm not even sure if this is possible, so let me know if it isn't. What I'm looking for is a way to set two possible file paths for an image (SVG file) for an icon, such that if the image isn't at the first file path/location, it'll try the second. I have an object like so:

```
this.bookmarkButtonConfig = {
    "oc-control": "BookmarkButton",
    "label": "BookmarkButton",
    "group": "primary",
    "action": "onBookmark",
    "buttonType": "toggle",
    "image": "$MODULE_PATH/images/favorite-icon.svg"
}
```

All of these properties are then being read by something else and configuring a button based on said properties, but that's not important for this. Is there a way that I can set the `"image"` so that it'll look for the icon at one file path, and then if it's not there, it'll try a second file path? Is there some sort of function or method that could do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See if this helps. check image availability (before this.bookmarkButtonConfig = {....}) and store its path in a variable. Then use that variable with your "image"

Comment: Do you have any framework use?

Comment: @ChristianEsperar I can't add any frameworks, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using an AJAX call to check if the image exists in the server,
first write this function:

```
function imageExists(url){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;
}
```

Then assign the url depending on the result like this:

```
var src = imageExists(the first url) ? "the first url" : "the second url";
```

Comment: In the fourth line, is image_url supposed to be "url", as in the argument the function takes?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I mean, is the second argument of the http.open() supposed to be the same as the parameter of the imageExists() function?

Comment: No the function imageExists(variable) will take any variable (which will be an URL) and it will perform an AJAX call to see if the file exists, if it does it will return true, otherwise it will return false.
So in your script you will call this function and you'll pass to it the URL that you want to test its availability ;)

Comment: Ah okay. got it.